# Failed to connect to repository:Command "D:\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h -- http://serverIp:port/cb/git/project HEAD" returned status code 128:err503

Tags: git, repository, http-status-code-503

Failed to connect to repository : Command "D:\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h -- http://serverIp:port/cb/git/project HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'http://serverIp:port/cb/git/project/': The requested URL returned error: 503

I am trying to connect Git hosted on our server to Jenkins hosted on another server

Comment: 503 means "service unavailable", so look at the server logs to see why the server is deciding it cannot answer. (This is almost certainly a web-server configuration error and thus has nothing to do with Git.)

Comment: @torek these are windows servers so where exactly I need to check

Comment: I don't know; I don't do Windows (just Linux, macOS, BSD, etc).